# Does QCA support SHA-2 hashing?

Tags: qt, hash, cryptography, shared-libraries

Does QCA (Qt Cryptographic Architecture) support SHA-2 (SHA256 in particular)? If not: Is there a plug-in for SHA-2 hashing in Qt?

Please let me know some configuration details as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does, by adding the *OSSL provider plugin*:

http://delta.affinix.com/qca/

See the table at the bottom of the page.

A tutorial on how to install and include QCA with this provider plugin can be found here (for both Linux and Windows/mingw32 environments):

http://www.essentialunix.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48:qcatutorial&catid=34:qttutorials&Itemid=53

You can then check it during runtime of your application using this code snippet:

```
QCA::init();
if(!QCA::isSupported("sha2"))
    qFatal("SHA-2 not supported!");
```

---

For very-high-security projects (for which you need a software certificate or a professional code review) you could also use *Crypto++*, which is a certified library providing SHA-2 out of the box:

http://www.cryptopp.com/

For the certified versions, see the section *FIPS 140-2 Conformance* at the bottom of the page. Note that the certified versions are for Windows only.

---

Note that Qt 5 has SHA-2 built-in:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcryptographichash.html#Algorithm-enum

I guess that you want your application to be Qt 4 compatible. However, you should think about using the built-in SHA-2 implementation if your application is compiled with Qt5, which can be done using preprocessor conditions and in the .pro file conditional library inclusion.

Comment: thanks a lot for your info..i have tried ossl plugin but may be i did mistake which didn't make itself to run successively. I have configure successfully in qt.Can you please tell me how to configure ossl in Qt with mingw toolchain ?

Comment: my pro. file for qt with qca looks like this..                     QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = hash
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += -LC:/Qt/hash/qca-2.0.3/lib -lqca2


INCLUDEPATH += "F:/QtSDK/qca-2.0.3/include/QtCrypto"
CONFIG += crypto

Comment: Did you place both DLL files for QCA and the OSSL plugin in your application directory? What's the error message? Your .pro file looks correct to me as I guess that you do not need to write anything to include the OSSL provider plugin into this file. (The provider is loaded during runtime.) Also note that I updated the answer and included a code snippet to check the availability of SHA-2 during runtime. Once you succeed running the application, you should get `true` from `QCA::isSupported("sha2")` if the OSSL DLL was found.

Comment: @muktoshuvro Here is a nice tutorial for both Linux and Windows (mingw): http://www.essentialunix.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48:qcatutorial&catid=34:qttutorials&Itemid=53.

Comment: some stuff i don't get it correctly from this link..they said "Rename the files libeay32.a and ssleay32.a to libeay32.lib and ssleay32.lib"    is it a write way to change formats of lib file ? also i can't find this file qca-ossl.cpp file in ossl plugin directory...is this i should download and change the source code as they said than put in application directory ?? any clue ?? i have put all the DLL of QCA in my application directory. but there is no DLL file in OSSL plug in folger rather than they have some .a file

Comment: Try to download the sources and compile both QCA and QCA-OSSL. The step about renaming those files seems strange to me. Let me follow the same tutorial and I'll report what steps are important. Maybe the tutorial writer has overlooked something...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15235/discussion-between-muktoshuvro-and-leemes)

Comment: the second link is broken

Comment: @IspasClaudiu Thanks, fixed it.